# Hierarchical templates of controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, controls

I am not sure the hierarchical template of wpf controls. For example, for a combobox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}, Path=DataContext.IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}">
                     </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

It might have control template something like, but I don't know.

combox has a template son ItemTemplate and a grandson DateTemplate. So for a control, how many template sons and grandsons? Can we enumerate them all and relations in a chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain difference between the *names* of the properties and their *types* in the following:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <!-- Add a DataTemplate here. It determines how the content 
               of your data item appears. Use it to bind data 
               fields or format string and etc -->
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <!-- Add a Style here. It determines the appearance of the
               element (e.g., ComboBoxItem) that contains the data. Set
               Selection behaviour, Background color, etc-->
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.Template>
          <!-- Add a ControlTemplate here. It contains the tree of 
               elements that define the desired look. Of course, most of
               the time, you do not set this property and use the default 
               value. Use it for example to change the shape of the ToggleButton.-->
    </ComboBox.Template>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
          <!-- Add an ItemsPanelTemplate here. Use it to determine the 
               the panel that the ItemsPresenter creates for the Items. 
               You can change the orientation of the ComboBoxItems here .-->
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: So this for combobox. In the general control, say if it is a button, does it have the same pattern?

Comment: No, a Button does not have ``ItemTemplate``, ``ItemContainerStyle`` and ``ItemsPanel``. These are specific to [``ItemsControl``](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and other controls derived from it, such as ``ListBox``, ``TreeView``, etc. ``Button`` has a ``Template`` property of type ``ControlTemplate``. In fact, it does not need these properties.

Comment: So each control has its own pattern. How can I memory these?

Comment: After a few weeks working (living) with them, you will learn their patterns. It's not that complicated. ;)